# Combobox items from a list c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to C# a little help please.
I'm trying to set items of a combobox from another class's method.

```
public void Province(String province)
{
     //NAConst obj = new NAConst();
     province = UppercaseFirst(province);
     //string tempVar;
     List<string> disttListB = new List<string>();
     disttListB.Add("Quetta");
     disttListB.Add("Chaman");
     disttListB.Add("Gawadar");
     disttListB.Add("Kalat");
}
```

This form takes a province name from textbox of form1 and should return a list of district names accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the return type from `void` to `List<string>`

```
public List<string> Province(String province)
{
     //NAConst obj = new NAConst();
     province = UppercaseFirst(province);
     //string tempVar;
     List<string> disttListB = new List<string>();
     disttListB.Add("Quetta");
     disttListB.Add("Chaman");
     disttListB.Add("Gawadar");
     disttListB.Add("Kalat");

     return disttListB;
}
```

You can then `return` the List `disttListB`.

You can then invoke the method as follows and assign it to the `ComboBox DataSource`:

```
var districts = Province("province");
combobox.DataSource = districts;
```

As an additional note, you're not using the `province` variable after you have assigned it so not entirely sure what you wish to do there.

Answer (score 0):

First you need change the return type from `void` to `List<string>`:

```
public List<string> Province(String province)
{
     //NAConst obj = new NAConst();
     province = UppercaseFirst(province);
     //string tempVar;
     List<string> disttListB = new List<string>();
     disttListB.Add("Quetta");
     disttListB.Add("Chaman");
     disttListB.Add("Gawadar");
     disttListB.Add("Kalat");

     return disttListB;
}
```

Then you need to set that as source to your combobox:

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox(); // your Combobox
cb.ItemsSource = Province("SomeText");
```